# minimization problem for elliptic system

Tags: partial-differential-equations, eigenfunctions

Consider the following minimization problem in $\mathbb{R}^N$:
$$
\lambda_1(R)：=\min_{(\zeta_i)_{i=1}^m \in H_0^1(B_R(0))}
\biggl\{\sum_{i=1}^m \int_{B_R(0)}|\nabla\zeta_i|^2 + \sum_{i,j=1}^m \int_{B_R(0)} H_{ij}\zeta_i\zeta_j
\Biggm| \sum_{i=1}^m \int_{B_R(0)} \zeta_i^2 = 1 \biggr\},
$$
where $H_{ij}\in C(\mathbb{R}^N)$ satisfies
$$
\sum_{i=1}^m \int_{B_R(0)}|\nabla\zeta_i|^2 + \sum_{i,j=1}^m \int_{B_R(0)} H_{ij}\zeta_i\zeta_j \geq 0
$$
for every $\zeta_k\in C_c^1(B_R(0))$.

It's said in [this paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00526-012-0536-x) (Page 816) that there exist eigenfunctions $(\zeta_i^R)_{i=1}^m$ such that
$$
\Delta\zeta_i^R = \sum_j H_{ij} \zeta_j^R - \lambda_1(R)\zeta_i^R
\quad\text{in}\ B_R(0),
$$
and $\zeta_i^R = 0$ on $\partial B_R(0)$.

In the classical case, this kind of result can be found in Evans' book, Walter Strauss' book, etc. I want to know how to prove this assertion for system.

Any references about minimization problem and first eigenvalue-eigenfunction of elliptic systems are really appreciated!